# Why are my Preprocessor Directives locked

Tags: c#, preprocessor-directive

I've done lots of research but haven't found any answers yet.

I'm working on a plugin to run inside a proprietary program called Autodesk Revit. This plugin needs to be distributed to 3x different companies, each using the their own filing system.

I'm storing some file paths in read-only fields in a separate static class in another project in VS but within the same solution and used preprocessing directives to define symbols named after each company I'm distributing the plugin to. I then set each field to different file paths under preprocessing #if, #elif, etc, so I can just define/undefine the symbols before compiling the code so I can distribute them to each appropriate company (sample code below).

I have no conditional compilation symbols setup in the property of either project and I realise I can use config files for that as well but since this plugin is running inside a host program there are some workarounds needed to get that to work which I'd rather avoid.

Regardless of what symbol I define or undefine, my plugin is pointing at COMPANYB at all times. What am I missing?

```
#define COMPANYA
#undef COMPANYB
#undef COMPANYC

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class FileLocations
    {
#if COMPANYA
            public static string fieldA => @"\\serverNameA\filenameA.rte";
            public static string fieldB => @"\\serverNameA\filenameB.rte";
            public static string UsageFolder => @"\\serverNameA\ScriptUsage\";


#elif COMPANYB
            public static string fieldA => @"\\serverNameB\filenameA.rte";
            public static string fieldB => @"\\serverNameB\filenameB.rte";
            public static string UsageFolder => @"C:\Temp\";


#elif COMPANYC
            public static string fieldA => @"\\serverNameC\filenameA.rte";
            public static string fieldB => @"\\serverNameC\filenameB.rte";
            public static string UsageFolder => @"C:\Temp\";
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Build > Clean after you switch.  https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I am curious about your example. Are you really storing tenant data as string constants like this? Have you considered using config transforms, or resource files, or code generation? There is a lot of risk in this design as there is no way to QA it and no way to modify it after it has released.

Comment: Looks like bad use of PP. Not sure about c#, but with cpp you've got "#if" and "#ifdef" - you seem to be mixing the two.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately the clean didn't work but thanks.

Comment: @JohnWu I've never used any of those 3x options but I'll definitely look into them, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My VS solution has two projects which are two plugins (plugin A and plugin B) which run inside the main program (Autodesk Revit). Both plugins share what I call "helper classes" which I created as a third project in the solution.

I updated one of the helper classes and rebuilt plugin A but plugin B had an old version of the helper class dll in the folder which seemed to be taking precedence over the new one. Once I replaced that dll as well plugin A worked as expected.

I'm fairly new to programming (approx 2 years) and self taught, every bit of advice is very welcome to help me avoid these issues in the future.